# "Rather !" as a reply: old-fashioned? Colloquial? Unusual?

Tags: british-english, word-usage

Is "Rather" as a reply (BrE), with heavy stress on the second syllable, old-fashioned ?  Colloquial ?  Unusual ?

> e.g. "Did you enjoy yourself?"   "Rather!"

Can "pretty much so!" be its AmE counterpart?

Comment: If I understand "rather!", correctly as an *emphatic affirmation*, then "pretty much so!" seems much weaker to my American ear. If "rather!" is also intended to have a bit of a sarcastic or ironic tone, then "*pretty much!*" (dropping the *so*) might be a closer analog, but frankly I'd more likely say "*Hell yeah!*".

Comment: There are so many ways an AmE speaker might say so, "pretty much so" probably doesn't get much use: Yeah. Yes. Way! Very much. I did! hell yeah. It was awesome.  Quite a bit. Are you kidding?! ...

Comment: @DanBron  Would it be considered rude to say "Hell yeah" before a couple of old ladies ?  I'm asking this because "hell" is a somewhat strong word in my mother tongue.

Comment: You probably wouldn't say it in front of grandma, no, but it also likely wouldn't be a big deal if you did. A milder version is "for sure!".

Comment: In the US, one might say, *Absolutely* or *Very much*.

Comment: Or just remove the `so`, most Americans would understand `pretty much` as answering in the affirmative.

Comment: Saying 'Pretty much' indicates a so-so response- meaning (in this case) that in some ways you did enjoy it but in some ways you may not have but on balance your level of enjoyment was positive.

Comment: @medica Wait, you mean I’m ***not*** supposed to respond with *Rather!* in America? For real‽ Nobody ever warns me about these things, dangnabbit!  Is it only the dry version that is forbidden, or is the emphatic one also apt to get me cited for an offsides penalty of some sort?

Comment: To answer the first question: The sentence substitute usage was always rather high-flown in register. Expect to encounter it in 'The Famous Five' etc books and films etc about the RAF in the Second World War, and/or featuring Terry Thomas or Bertie Wooster. I'd say the usage has been considered an affectation since say 1960.

Comment: BrE is often quite understated and uses a fair bit of litotes in its converstaional language. Rather feels very British to me, where I would expect an AmE speaker to more likely say something like "totally!", which is somewhat more overstated. (Apologies for American stereotyping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit old-fashioned; a little toffish.

As is typical with English understatement, its meaning is more emphatic that you think - it would synonymous with "yes, absolutely".

```
Jeremy: "She's a fine specimen; graceful lines with a touch of elegance."

Quentin: "Rather!"
```

(Talking about a ship, obviously ;) )